# How to get page specific layout ignore all the previous layouts in nextjs

Tags: next.js

path for this page : src\app(dynamic-pages)(authenticated-pages)(user-pages)\project(specific-project-pages)\modelswap\page.tsx

```
export default function ProjectPage() {
  return (
    <div className="space-y-6">
      <div className="mb-10">
       hello model
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

path for parent layout`your text` : src\app(dynamic-pages)(authenticated-pages)(user-pages)\layout.tsx

```
export default async function Layout({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <>
      <InternalNavbar />
      <div className="relative flex-1 h-auto w-full overflow-auto">
        <div className="px-12 space-y-6 pb-10">{children}</div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

}

i want a blank page for ProjectPage layout